# How to perform print job on server?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, windows-xp, printer

Unfortunately, my old printer does not have a working driver in Windows 7. So I decided to install Windows XP Mode and install its printer driver in the virtual Windows XP. Then I attached the printer to the VM (it is a USB printer BTW) and I was able to print from within XP.

Now, here comes the question: is there a way to have the printer added in the printers list on my Windows 7 host, but make it send the jobs to the VM (it is powered on most of the time), so that the driver pops up with the ink level dialogs I am used to seeing every time I printed something on my previous Windows XP installation? Is there a way to handle network print jobs on the computer linked to the printer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, any computer that prints to a networked, non-local printer uses a driver for that printer to format the print data or uses a generic formatting method that the printer understands.  The same would apply between the host the the VM.

You might be able to get the printer to work with Win 7.  Some people occassionally have luck using a driver for a different model printer from the same manufacturer (large groups of printers share the same instruction set).  Do an Internet search and check the Windows support forums to see if someone has reported success with a different driver, or look for another, similar printer from the same manufacturer that does have a Win 7 driver and try it.  If it doesn't work, just uninstall the driver.

If you're lucky, you might be able to send properly formatted print jobs, but asking for internal hardware data, like ink levels, is far less likely unless a "sister" model has a Win 7 driver.